# Sharepoint 2010 get all list items from all lists with javascript

Tags: 2010, list, javascript

I want to get all list items from all lists in SharePoint 2010 with JavaScript. I always get the error:

> SCRIPT5022: The collection has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.

Here is my code:

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(receivedAllLists, "SP.js");

function receivedAllLists() {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();
    this.collList = oWebsite.get_lists();
    clientContext.load(collList);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onreceivedAllListsSucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onreceivedAllListsSucceeded() {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();
    var listInfo = '';

    var listEnumerator = collList.getEnumerator();

    while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oList = listEnumerator.get_current();
        oList = oWebsite.get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle); 
        var splistquery = new SP.CamlQuery();
        splistitems = oList.getItems(splistquery);
        clientContext.load(splistitems, 'Include(Id)');
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onrecieveAllListItemsSucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
    }
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Fail');
}


function onrecieveAllListItemsSucceeded() {


    var listItemInfo = '';
    var listItemEnumerator = splistitems.getEnumerator();

    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
    var currentlistitem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();

    }

}
```

Comment: For which execute query you are getting this error?

Comment: I get the error in the second execute query.

Answer (score 0):

You should not call `executeQueryAsync` method in loop as it will generate multiple async calls and execution will get messed up in deciding which `onrecieveAllListItemsSucceeded` method to execute. That is reason most of the time we get error `The collection has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.`
Check this link for similar issue resolved https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/146869/40602