# Cannot execute JSOM code correctly

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, jsom

I am iterating List A and fetching each items title. Then I match the title against a column in List B. If a match is found I add relevant columns in list B and output.
I have put 2 items in list A as test data. Though I can see the code in List B being called twice (I get the alert 'Part2 -' xx) I only get the 'Output alert' once and only the last item in List A is being worked on.
I think the problem is in the 2nd section while loop. 
Any ideas please?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(TeamRequests, "SP.js");

function TeamRequests() {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('TeamRequests');        
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View></View>');
    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
    clientContext.load(collListItem);        
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceededTeamRequests), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailedTeamRequests)); 
}

function onQuerySucceededTeamRequests(sender, args) {
    var listItemInfo = ''; var iCount=0;

    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();

       listItemInfo += '\nID: ' + oListItem.get_id() +  '\nTitle: ' + oListItem.get_item('Title');

// Code to get Mandays
//alert (oListItem.get_item('Title'));
    Mandays(oListItem.get_item('Title'));

        }
  // alert (listItemInfo);
}

function onQueryFailedTeamRequests(sender, args) {
    alert('TeamRequests Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}    
function Mandays(trTitle)
{
    alert (trTitle);
    this.trTitle = trTitle;
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Mandays');        
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View></View>');
    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
    clientContext.load(collListItem);        
    //clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceededMandays), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailedMandays));        

     clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function(){onQuerySucceededMandays(trTitle);}), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailedMandays));        



}

//function onQuerySucceededMandays(sender, args) {


function onQuerySucceededMandays(trPassTitle) {

alert ('part2 -' +  trPassTitle);
    var option1=0; option2=0; option3=0;

    var listItemInfo = ''; var iCount=0;

    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();


    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();

       listItemInfo += '\nID: ' + oListItem.get_id() +  '\nTitle: ' + oListItem.get_item('Title')+  '\nTRTitle: ' + oListItem.get_item('TeamRequest_x003a_Title').get_lookupValue();

        //test for Team
        alert ('trPassTitle -'+ trPassTitle + '\n Man -'+ oListItem.get_item('TeamRequest_x003a_Title').get_lookupValue());
        if (trPassTitle == (oListItem.get_item('TeamRequest_x003a_Title').get_lookupValue())) 
        {
            if (oListItem.get_item('Item') == 'Option1') {
                option1 += parseFloat(oListItem.get_item('EstCost')); }
            if (oListItem.get_item('Item') == 'Option2') {
                option2 += parseFloat(oListItem.get_item('EstCost')); }
            if (oListItem.get_item('Item') == 'Option3') {
                option3 += parseFloat(oListItem.get_item('EstCost')); }
        }

    } // end while
    alert ('Output Option1 ' + option1 + '\nOption2 ' + option2 + '\nOption3 ' + option3);

    //  alert (listItemInfo);
    //return;
}

function onQueryFailedMandays(sender, args) {

    alert('Mandays Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}



</script>
```

Comment: seems like you have an exception intercepting your code - did you check the dev tools? press F12 in your browser to access them.

Comment: Developer tools report:
SCRIPT5022: The collection has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested. 
sp.runtime.js?rev=IGffcZfunndj0247nOxKVg%3D%3D, line 2 character 23256

Comment: with the devtools you can check wich line the error occurs and even debug your code - your problem is a pretty obvios one.
when you try to access an item that you havent load via `ctx.load`, this error occurs. I bet its in line `var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();`

Comment: When I 'step over' code  var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
is highlighted. I tried adding 
clientContext.load(collListItem,'Include(Item,TeamRequest_x003a_Title,Title,Id)'); but error remains

Comment: probably the wrong scope. but you should have enough infomations to solve it yourself. fiddling arround with the devtools will help you learn the language

Comment: Could this be issue as I'm using javascript asynchronous behaviour ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25001/discussion-between-orange-juice-and-mx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I refactored (not tested!) your code - you shouldnt have any scoping issues now.

```
/* global SP */
/* global ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded */
(function() {
    //here we are in our own scope - no messing with other globals (SharePoint has a lot)
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function() {
        //if you use a function only once - you dont necessarily need a function 
        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('TeamRequests');
        var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery();
        var collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
        clientContext.load(collListItem);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
            function() {
                //success
                var listItemInfo = '';
                var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

                while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                    var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
                    listItemInfo += '\nID: ' + oListItem.get_id() + '\nTitle: ' + oListItem.get_item('Title');
                    // Code to get Mandays
                    Mandays(oListItem.get_item('Title'));
                }
                //alert (listItemInfo);
            },
            function(sender, args) {
                console.log(sender);
                console.log(args);
                alert('TeamRequests Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
            }
        );
    }, "SP.js");

    function Mandays(trTitle) {
        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Mandays');
        var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery();
        var collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
        clientContext.load(collListItem);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
            function() {
                //success
                alert('part2 -' + trTitle);
                var option1 = 0,
                    option2 = 0,
                    option3 = 0,
                    listItemInfo = '';

                var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
                while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                    var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();

                    listItemInfo += '\nID: ' + oListItem.get_id() + '\nTitle: ' + oListItem.get_item('Title') + '\nTRTitle: ' + oListItem.get_item('TeamRequest_x003a_Title').get_lookupValue();

                    //test for Team
                    alert('trPassTitle -' + trTitle + '\n Man -' + oListItem.get_item('TeamRequest_x003a_Title').get_lookupValue());
                    if (trTitle == (oListItem.get_item('TeamRequest_x003a_Title').get_lookupValue())) {
                        if (oListItem.get_item('Item') == 'Option1') {
                            option1 += parseFloat(oListItem.get_item('EstCost'));
                        }
                        if (oListItem.get_item('Item') == 'Option2') {
                            option2 += parseFloat(oListItem.get_item('EstCost'));
                        }
                        if (oListItem.get_item('Item') == 'Option3') {
                            option3 += parseFloat(oListItem.get_item('EstCost'));
                        }
                    }
                }
                alert('Output Option1 ' + option1 + '\nOption2 ' + option2 + '\nOption3 ' + option3);
            },
            function(sender, args) {
                console.log(sender);
                console.log(args);
                alert('TeamRequests Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
            }
        );
    }
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

you should not call a function in loop which is having `executeQueryAsyc()` method in it because of the asynchronous nature of the method. The while loop will create multiple async calls and code execution will get messed up to decide which `querySucceed()` method to execute. Thats why the error `The collection has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.`

I have made some changes to your code. Check if it works for you.

```
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(TeamRequests, "SP.js");
    function TeamRequests() {
        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('TeamRequests');        
        var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
        camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View></View>');
        this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
        clientContext.load(collListItem);        
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceededTeamRequests), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailedTeamRequests));        
    }
    function onQuerySucceededTeamRequests(sender, args) {
        var listItemInfo = ''; var iCount=0;
        var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
        var arrTitle = [];
        while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
            var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
            listItemInfo += '\nID: ' + oListItem.get_id() +  '\nTitle: ' + oListItem.get_item('Title');
            //Mandays(oListItem.get_item('Title'));
            if(oListItem.get_item('Title')!= null){
                arrTitle.push(oListItem.get_item('Title'));
            }
        }
        Mandays(arrTitle);
    }
    function onQueryFailedTeamRequests(sender, args) {
        alert('TeamRequests Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }
    function Mandays(arrTitle)
    {
        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Mandays');        
        var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
        var strQueryStart = "<View><Query><Where><In><FieldRef Name='TeamRequest_x003a_Title' /><Values>";
        var strQueryMiddle = "";
        for(var i = 0; i < arrTitle.length; i++){
            strQueryMiddle += "<Value Type='Lookup'>"+arrTitle[i]+"</Value>";  /////for getting only those "TeamRequest_x003a_Title" which are equals to Title from "TeamRequests"
        }
        var strQueryEnd = "</Values></In></Where></Query></View>";
        camlQuery.set_viewXml(strQueryStart + strQueryMiddle + strQueryEnd);
        this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
        clientContext.load(collListItem);        
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceededMandays), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailedMandays));
    }
    //function onQuerySucceededMandays(sender, args) {
    function onQuerySucceededMandays(trPassTitle) {
        var option1=0; option2=0; option3=0;
        var listItemInfo = ''; var iCount=0;
        var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
        while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
            var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
            listItemInfo += '\nID: ' + oListItem.get_id() +  '\nTitle: ' + oListItem.get_item('Title')+  '\nTRTitle: ' + oListItem.get_item('TeamRequest_x003a_Title').get_lookupValue();
            /////we don't need this condition here as we already have such records which full fill this condition
            //if (trPassTitle == (oListItem.get_item('TeamRequest_x003a_Title').get_lookupValue())) 
            //{
            if (oListItem.get_item('Item') == 'Option1') {
                option1 += parseFloat(oListItem.get_item('EstCost')); }
            if (oListItem.get_item('Item') == 'Option2') {
                option2 += parseFloat(oListItem.get_item('EstCost')); }
            if (oListItem.get_item('Item') == 'Option3') {
                option3 += parseFloat(oListItem.get_item('EstCost')); }
            //}
        } // end while
        alert ('Output Option1 ' + option1 + '\nOption2 ' + option2 + '\nOption3 ' + option3);
    }
    function onQueryFailedMandays(sender, args) {
        alert('Mandays Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }
```

Comment: Hi The code executes but result is incorrect. When I add a few items with the same TeamRequest then I get a single alert showing totals of Option1-3, this is ok. If I add another few  **different** TeamRequest I still only get the same single alert but now summing up all the options.
I need to display a matrix with TeamRequest, Option1,Option2, Option3 for every Team Request in the TeamRequest list  (in the TeamRequest list I  have a single instance of every team and in the Mandays I have multiples, the options of the multiples are needed to be added only)

Comment: Try using `alert ('Output Option1 ' + option1 + '\nOption2 ' + option2 + '\nOption3 ' + option3);` in while loop so that in each iteration it will show the values of options 1, 2 & 3.

Comment: It outputs the values of every item in Mandays without any order. in the while I need to add condition that checks for the value in the array from the calling function trPassTitle . How can it be passed ?